# R prediction within an interval

Tags: r, machine-learning, glm, prediction, random-forest

quick question on prediction.

The value I’m trying to predict is either 0 or 1 (it is set as numeric, not as a factor) so when I run my random forest:

```
fit <- randomForest(PredictValue ~ <variables>, data=trainData, ntree=50)
```

and predict:

```
pred<-predict(fit, testData)
```

all my predictions are between 0 and 1 – which is what I expect and - I Imagine - can be interpreted as the probability of being 1.

Now, If I go through the same process using the gbm algorithm:

```
fitgbm <- gbm(PredictValue~ <variables>, data=trainData, distribution = "bernoulli", n.trees = 500,   bag.fraction = 0.75, cv.folds = 5, interaction.depth = 3)
predgbm <- predict(fitgbm, testData)
```

the values are from -0.5 to 0.5

I also tried glm and the range was worst, from around -3 to 3.

So, my question is: is it possible to set the algorithms to predict between 0 and 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `type='response'` for this to happen:

Check this example:

```
y <- rep(c(0,1),c(100,100))
x <- runif(200)
df <- data.frame(y,x)


fitgbm <- gbm(y ~ x, data=df, 
              distribution = "bernoulli", n.trees = 100)

predgbm <- predict(fitgbm, df, n.trees=100, type='response')
```

Too simplistic but look at the summary of `predgbm`:

```
> summary(predgbm)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.4936  0.4943  0.5013  0.5000  0.5052  0.5073
```

And as the documentation mentions this is the probability of y being 1:

> If type="response" then gbm converts back to the same scale as the outcome. Currently the only effect this will have is returning probabilities for bernoulli and expected counts for poisson.

Comment: that's great, thanks very much but I have another question if you don't mind. If I fit a forest on your example: fitforest <- randomForest(y ~ x, data = df, ntree = 100);  predforest <- predict(fitforest,df) and compare the min and max of both I get:


min(predgbm): 0.4892006; max(predgbm): 0.5070799  AND min(predforest): 0 max(predForest): 1

why is the gbm range so smaller than the forest?

thanks again

Comment: Sure np! It is because they are fundamentally different algorithms. The random forest takes a vote among the trees to define the class of the observation whereas the gbm tries to predict the the class with a first tree and then the other trees predict the errors the first one made according to a loss function (in many cases just the residual). It then classifies according to the sign of the addition of the trees. Hope it is a bit clearer.

Comment: I think this will also make it clearer. This is a pretty simple example and there will be cases where all the trees will predict 1 or 0 for a specific case and therefore you get a probability of 0 or 1 in a random forest. In the case of the gbm apart from the first tree (which I think predicts with -1 or 1) everything else will predict the errors and thus numeric numbers which will get added on 1s or -1s and the sign of the total in the end will determine the class. There is no majority vote on a gbm.

Comment: thanks, it does make sense, it just a little hard to digest because I have test rows that are 100% similar to train rows (that I added - to the test - just to check the algorithms accuracy) and gbm predicts as 0.6 while forest predicts as 1.

Comment: Yeah it can definitely happen (it has happened to me many times). It all depends on how the trees get created in the first place.

Comment: do you suggest a better algorithm to predict the probability the way I;m doing?

Comment: It really depends on the data you have. Different data need different algorithms. Random forests and knn algorithms are considered local solution algorithms whereas gbm is not. In my experience but that is only as a rule of thumb gbm works much better than a random forest. Both of these can predict probabilities so there is no better way really.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that many algorithms (even the same algorithm in different packages) just run a logistic regression with the cases in the terminal nodes to determine probabilities, so there isn't really a best or better way. (you could even try a logistic regression if your data is linear to predict probabilities).

Comment: No worries mate. Happy to have helped :)